# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I want to find $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n^3}$ by using method from this link :
http://www.supermath.info/InfiniteSeriesandtheResidueTheorem.pdf

Since $f(z)=\frac{\sin{z}}{z^3}$ has a pole at $z=0$,

I get that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty ,n\neq0}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n^3}=-Res_{z=0}\left(\frac{\pi\sin{z}\cot{(\pi z)}}{z^3}\right)=\frac{2\pi^2+1}{6}$
.

That is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n^3}=\frac{2\pi^2+1}{12}$.

But wolfram compute that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n^3}=\frac{(\pi-1)(2\pi-1)}{12}$.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+sin(n)%2Fn%5E3,+n%3D1+to+inf

How am I wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: the pole $z=0$ is double.

Comment: @GCab It doesn't really matter: I did the Laurent series and got the same residue as the OP.

Comment: @GCab : You mean has order 3? $$\frac{\pi\sin z\cos(\pi z)}{z^3\,\sin(\pi z)}$$

Comment: @Ble In the link you give there's only a result with the polylogarithm. Where did you get that number from?

Comment: @DonAntonio : It is in "Alternate forms" which is in the 6th box of the WA answer.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks, not I saw it.

Comment: @LutzL: I mean that the pole of $sin z/z^3$ (at z=0) is of second order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not apply the approach from that paper directly as the key assumption of theorem 3.2 
$$
|f(z)|\le \frac{M}{|z|^k}
$$
for some $k>1$ and all large $z$, $|z|>R$ for some large $R$, is not satisfied for $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z^3}$ as the sine function is exponential in the imaginary directions,
$$
\sin(z)=\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)
$$

Answer (score 6):

The best way to compute such series is using periodic functions. Suppose $f$ is periodic with period $2\pi$ and is equal to ${x^{3}\over3}-{{\pi x^{2}\over 2}}+{{\pi ^{2}x}\over 6}$ in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. The Fourier series of this function is $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} {\sin(2nx)\over n^{3}}$. Therefore replacing $x=0.5$ the result jumps out!

Comment: very cute approach

Comment: That's kind of you!

Answer (score 2):

The challenge can be met using the methods outlined in the notes mentioned by the OP: [http://www.supermath.info/InfiniteSeriesandtheResidueTheorem.pdf](https://www.supermath.info/InfiniteSeriesandtheResidueTheorem.pdf) if you consider the appropriate sum. You evaluate the sum

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\sin (nx)}{n^3}
\end{align*}

over the interval $-\pi < x < \pi$, and then at the end of the calculation make the shift $x \mapsto x-\pi$ to obtain the answer to

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (nx)}{n^3}
\end{align*}

over the interval $0 < x < 2 \pi$. Then finally, put $x=1$.

So

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty, n \not=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\sin (nx)}{n^3} = - Res_{z=0} \left( \frac{\pi \sin (zx) \csc (\pi z)}{z^3} \right) = \frac{x^3 - \pi^2 x}{6}  \qquad  (*)
\end{align*}

Note we are using $\csc (\pi z)$ instead of $\cot (\pi z)$, and as we will see in a moment, the value of $|\sin (xz) \csc (\pi z)|$ around the square $C_N$ is bounded by a constant that is independent of $N$, and as such the integral around $C_N$ will vanish as $N \rightarrow \infty$ (see referred pdf notes for definitions). Now, in $(*)$ we make the shift $x \mapsto x-\pi$ to obtain

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (nx)}{n^3} = \frac{(x-\pi)^3 - \pi^2 (x-\pi)}{12} = \frac{x (\pi-x) (2 \pi-x)}{12}
\end{align*}

Putting $x=1$, we obtain the desired result

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (n)}{n^3} = \frac{(\pi-1)(2\pi -1)}{12}
\end{align*}

CHECK THE INTEGRATION AROUND THE SQUARE $C_N$ VANISHES AS $N \rightarrow \infty$:

We consider summations of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \sin (nx)g(n)$ over the interval $-\pi < x < \pi$ where $g(-n) = - g(n)$.

Let $g(z)$ be analytic in $\mathbb{C}$ except for some finite set of
isolated singularities. We prove that if $|g(z)| \leq \frac{M}{|z|^k}$ along the path $C_N$, where $k > 1$ and $M$ are constants independent of $N$, then the integral around $C_N$ vanishes. Then we briefly establish a summation theorem.

We start by showing that the value of $|\sin (xz) \csc (\pi z)|$ around the square $C_N$ is bounded by a constant that is independent of $N$.

We write $z=X+iY$

Case 1: $Y > \frac{1}{2}$, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\left| \dfrac{\sin (z x)}{\sin (\pi z)} \right| &=& \left| \dfrac{e^{i z x} - e^{-i z x}}{e^{i \pi z} - e^{-i \pi z}} \right|
\nonumber \\
&=& \dfrac{|e^{i z x}| + |e^{-i z x}|}{|e^{i \pi z}| - |e^{-i \pi z}|}
\nonumber \\
&=& \dfrac{|e^{i x X - x Y}| + |e^{-i x X + xY}|}{|e^{i \pi X - \pi Y}| - |e^{-i \pi X + \pi Y}|}
\nonumber \\
&=& \dfrac{e^{- x Y} + e^{x Y}}{e^{\pi Y} - e^{-\pi Y}}
\nonumber \\
&=& \dfrac{e^{Y (x -\pi)} + e^{-Y (x+\pi)}}{1 - e^{- 2 \pi Y}}
\nonumber \\
&\leq& \dfrac{2}{1 - e^{- 2 \pi Y}}  \qquad \text{ as we are taking } -\pi < x < \pi
\nonumber \\
&\leq& \dfrac{2}{1 - e^{- \pi}}  \qquad \text{ as we are taking } Y > \frac{1}{2}
\nonumber \\
&=:& A_1 
\end{eqnarray}

Case 2: $Y < - \frac{1}{2}$, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\left| \dfrac{\sin (z x)}{\sin (\pi z)} \right| &=& \dfrac{|e^{i x X - x Y}| + |e^{-i x X + xY}|}{|e^{i \pi X - \pi Y}| - |e^{-i \pi X + \pi Y}|}
\nonumber \\
&=& \dfrac{e^{- x Y} + e^{x Y}}{e^{-\pi Y} - e^{\pi Y}}
\nonumber \\
&=& \dfrac{e^{-Y (x -\pi)} + e^{Y (x+\pi)}}{1 - e^{2 \pi Y}}
\nonumber \\
&\leq& \dfrac{2}{1 - e^{2 \pi Y}}  \qquad \text{ as we are taking } -\pi < x < \pi
\nonumber \\
&\leq& \dfrac{2}{1 - e^{-\pi}}  \qquad \text{ as we are taking } Y < - \frac{1}{2}
\nonumber \\
&=& A_1 
\end{eqnarray}

Case 3: $-\frac{1}{2} \leq Y \leq \frac{1}{2}$. We consider $z = N +\frac{1}{2} + iY$. We make repeated use of $\sin (\alpha + \beta) = \cos \alpha \sin \beta + \sin \alpha \cos \beta$ and $\cos (\alpha + \beta) = \cos \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \alpha \sin \beta$. In particular we will use:

\begin{align*}
\sin (\pi (N + \frac{1}{2} + i Y)) = \cos (\pi N) \sin (\pi/2  + i \pi Y) = (-1)^N \cosh (\pi Y)
\end{align*}

We have:

\begin{eqnarray}
&\;& \left| \dfrac{\sin (x (N + \frac{1}{2} + i Y))}{\sin (\pi (N + \frac{1}{2} + i Y))} \right| 
\nonumber \\
&=& \dfrac{| \cos (xN) \sin (x/2+ixY) + \sin (xN) \cos (x/2+ixY) |}{\cosh (\pi Y)}
\nonumber \\
&\leq& \dfrac{| \cos (xN) \sin (x/2+ixY)}{\cosh (\pi Y) |} + \dfrac{| \sin (xN) \cos (x/2+ixY) |}{\cosh (\pi Y)}
\nonumber \\
&\leq& \dfrac{| \sin (x/2+ixY)}{\cosh (\pi Y) |} + \dfrac{| \cos (x/2+ixY)}{\cosh (\pi Y) |}
\nonumber \\
&\leq& \dfrac{| \cos (x/2) \sin (ixY) + \sin (x/2) \cos (ixY) |}{\cosh (\pi Y)}  + \dfrac{| \cos (x/2) \cos (ixY) - \sin (x/2) \sin (ixY) |}{\cosh (\pi Y)}
\nonumber \\
&\leq& 2 \dfrac{| \sinh (xY) |}{\cosh (\pi Y)} + 2 \dfrac{\cosh (xY)}{\cosh (\pi Y)}
\nonumber \\
&=& 2 \dfrac{| e^{xY} - e^{-xY} |}{e^{\pi Y} + e^{-\pi Y}} + 2 \dfrac{e^{xY} + e^{-xY}}{e^{\pi Y} + e^{-\pi Y}}
\nonumber \\
&\leq& 4 \dfrac{e^{xY} + e^{-xY}}{e^{\pi Y} + e^{-\pi Y}}
\nonumber \\
&=& 4 \dfrac{e^{Y (x - \pi)} + e^{-Y (x + \pi)}}{1 + e^{-\pi Y}}
\nonumber \\
&\leq& \dfrac{8 e^\pi}{1 + e^{-\pi / 2}}  \qquad \text{ as we are taking } -\pi < x < \pi \text{ and } -\frac{1}{2} \leq Y \leq \frac{1}{2}
\nonumber \\
&=:& A_2 
\end{eqnarray}

So choose $A$ such that $A > \max \{ A_1 , A_2 \}$. Then we have $|\sin (xz) \csc (\pi z)| < A$ on $C_N$ with an $A$ independent of $N$. Then

\begin{align*}
\left| \oint_{C_N} \csc (\pi z) \sin (xz) g(z) dz \right| \leq \frac{\pi A M}{N^k} (8N+4)
\end{align*}

as $(8N+4)$ is the length of the curve $C_N$. Letting $N \rightarrow \infty$ we get that the integral vanishes.

Q.E.D.

(Refer to mentioned pdf notes for a more comprehensive discussion supporting the subsequent summation theorem.). This means we have proven the summation formula

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty, n \not= 0}^\infty (-1)^n \sin (n x) g(n) = - Res_{z=0} ( \pi \csc ( \pi z) \sin (xz) g(z) ) - \sum \{ \text{ residues of } \pi \csc ( \pi z) \sin (xz) g(z) \text{ at } g's \text{ poles for } z \not= 0 \}
\end{align*}

for the interval $-\pi < x < \pi$.

As mentioned, at the end of the calculation we make the substitution $x \mapsto x - \pi$, thus obtaining

\begin{align*}
2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin (n x) g(n) =  - Res_{z=0} ( \pi \csc ( \pi z) \sin (z (x - \pi)) g(z) ) - \sum \{ \text{ residues of } \pi \csc ( \pi z) \sin (z (x - \pi)) g(z) \text{ at } g's \text{ poles for } z \not= 0 \}
\end{align*}

for the interval $0 < x < 2 \pi$ (we have used $g(-n) = - g(n)$).

Finally, we can put $x=1$ to obtain

\begin{align*}
2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin (n) g(n) =  - Res_{z=0} ( \pi \csc ( \pi z) \sin (z (1 - \pi)) g(z) ) - \sum \{ \text{ residues of } \pi \csc ( \pi z) \sin (z (1 - \pi)) g(z) \text{ at } g's \text{ poles for } z \not= 0 \}
\end{align*}

CHECK: We check that for the interval $0 < x < 2 \pi$ that the Fourier series of $\frac{(x-\pi)^3 - \pi^2 (x-\pi)}{12}$ is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (nx)}{n^3}$. Recall for the interval $0 < x < 2 \pi$,

\begin{align*}
s(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin (nx)
\end{align*}

where

\begin{align*}
b_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} s (x) \sin (nx)
\end{align*}

So, in our case

\begin{align*}
b_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{(x-\pi)^3 - \pi^2 (x-\pi)}{12} \sin (nx) dx = (-1)^n \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{y^3 - \pi^2 y}{12} \sin (ny) dy
\end{align*}

where we have put $y = x-\pi$. So

\begin{align*}
b_n & = (-1)^n \frac{1}{12 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (y^3 - \pi^2 y) \sin (ny) dy
\\
& = (-1)^n \frac{1}{6 \pi} \left. \left( \left[ \frac{d^3}{dk^3} + \pi^2 \frac{d}{dk} \right] \int_0^\pi \cos (ky) dy \right) \right|_{k=n}
\\
& = (-1)^n \frac{1}{6 \pi} \left. \left( \left[ \frac{d^3}{dk^3} + \pi^2 \frac{d}{dk} \right] \frac{1}{k} \cos (k \pi) \right) \right|_{k=n}
\\
& = \frac{1}{n^3}
\end{align*}